# Email newsletter php not working

Tags: php, newsletter

I am using a template and my newsletter is not working. i already have the website online.

```
if($_POST){

    $fileName = 'newsletter.txt'; //set 777 permision for this file. 
    $error = false;

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) 
        $error = true;


    //If all ok, save emali adress in file
    if($error == false){
        $file = fopen($fileName, a);
        fwrite($file, "$email,");
        fclose($file);
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Thats the [html and the php part](https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/15/).

```
<div class="span7">
    <form class="inline-form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="nlmail" class="span8" placeholder="Ingresá tu email" required />
        <button id="subscribe" class="button button-sp">Suscribite!</button>
    </form>
    <div id="err-subscribe" class="error centered">Por favor dejá un mail valido </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: Forms default to GET if a method is omitted.

Comment: Sidenote: I sure hope you're protecting that text file with all your might. Plus, 777; dangerous. Use 644.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to explicitly set `POST` inside your `<form>` for it to work:

```
<form class="inline-form" method="POST">
```

Note that it defaults to `GET` when omitted.

Sidenote: If this is a typo, you should fix this line:

```
$file = fopen($fileName, a); // missing quotes on "a"
```

Those modes needs to passed as string:

```
$file = fopen($fileName, 'a');
```

Comment: their submit button may need modifying too

Comment: @Fred-ii- you mean into `<input />`? i think its okay, its default is `type="submit"` also

Comment: they're using `<button...</button>`. There's no type for it neither.

Comment: Thank you very much bro , but its still not working.when i try to use it it pop up a sign that say ''the page at pymediar.com says
                                        an error ocurred

pd:i didnt fully understand the last part of that typo thing !

Comment: @SantiCengarle what i meant is, its just missing a quote, should be `$file = fopen($fileName, 'a');` the `a` need to have those

Comment: @Fred-ii- why? its okay, it'll still submit, for chrome and firefox at least :) works fine

Comment: i did what you told me bro , but still is not working !

Comment: @SantiCengarle does it say `OK`? is there an error on PHP? turn on error reporting before anything else, `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` _not working_ isn't gonna take us further solving it

Comment: No , it still say the same  ''an error ocurred'' ... 
Where do i have to write that code for the error reporting ?

Comment: @SantiCengarle just add that in your PHP, add those lines before anything else, is the form and the PHP on the same page?

Comment: @SantiCengarle are the PHP codes in the same file with the HTML? have you added the error reporting?

Comment: i have a folder with the newsletter.php, mail.php , functions.php  and the newsletter.txt....so that code is on the newsletter.php not in the index .Yes i did it, i put it below the '' <?php '' ... is that ok ?

Comment: @SantiCengarle yes you should put it in there, is this what `newsletter.php` contain? http://codepad.viper-7.com/xsYUok

Comment: @SantiCengarle i've went insdie your site, its a 500 error, make sure you don't have any errors in your PHP

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/15/
 thats the php file... and the html also ... 
i really dont know !

Comment: @SantiCengarle you haven't added the revision i made in my answer, `$file = fopen($fileName, 'a');` the `a` has to have that quote `'a'`

Comment: sorry man , yes i did it , but i did not uptdate the link .. there you go https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/17/

Comment: @SantiCengarle i've seen the site, the PHP is called by AJAX, its an error on your PHP, in your ajax it goes into this block `error: function (request, error) {
                    alert("An error occured");
                },` try to add `?>` on the end of your PHP

Comment: @SantiCengarle and make sure you have write permissions to the file

Comment: ok like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/18/   and how do i write presmission ? i dont know how to do it !

Comment: Sorryy, me internet went off last night ! ... uhm ... it says that i need to have 20 of reputation to participate on the chat !

Answer (score 0):

Well, here, the HTML form sends data as a GET, and the php is expecting a POST.

Change your HTML form to send data as POST.

```
 <form class="inline-form">
```

should be

```
 <form class="inline-form" method="POST">
```

Also, try debugging if the email variable is empty or not. Thats how you find whats wrong.

And also, the fopen mode should be in the quotes, unless its a variable.

```
$file = fopen($fileName, "a");
```

Cheers!

Comment: `var_dump` `$email` before and after the regex. Whats the outputs?